# android remove value from arraylist when button delete is clicked

Tags: java, android, arraylist

```
addberlian.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            removebutir = new ArrayList<Button>();
            final LinearLayout newView1 = (LinearLayout) getActivity()
                    .getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rowberlian, null);
            newView1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            butirberlian = (EditText) newView1.findViewById(R.id.butir);
            bntk = (EditText) newView1.findViewById(R.id.bentuk);
            karatberlian = (EditText) newView1.findViewById(R.id.totkarat); 
            btnRemoveberlian = (Button) newView1.findViewById(R.id.btnRemoveberlian);

            btnRemoveberlian.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     butir1.remove(butirberlian);   
                     ly3.removeView(newView1);
                } 
            });

            ly3.addView(newView1);
            butir1.add(butirberlian);           
            removebutir.add(btnRemoveberlian);
        }
    });

for(int i = 0; i< butir1.size();i++){
            butir.add(butir1.get(i).getText().toString());          
            TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
             tv.setText(""+butir.get(i));
             lyy.addView(tv);
```

I have edittext form and button delete that will be made dynamically for each time I click button add. the value from edittext is stored in arraylist. if i clicked on button delete, the edittext form will be removed. but the value is still not removed even after the edittext is removed. how can the value be removed after i click delete button?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your main question. The value still not removed xmlview or from arraylist?

Comment: arraylist.. actualy i already test using "remove" syntax but only the last value that been removed. not the selected one i choose.

Comment: Is this in a LinearLayout or a ListView?

Comment: I use linearlayout for make dynamic edittext and delete button

Answer (score 0):

try this for your delete button part

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.button);
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and xml file

```
<Button android:visibility="gone"/>
```